# Combine background image and text and pin it

Tags: c#, asp.net, social-networking, pinterest

I have a `<section>` tag with background image and containing text inside `<h4>`. I need to integrate it with Pinterest. If I will pin just an image I will lose the text. Is there a way to combine background image and text and pin it in "runtime".

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not exactly what you are looking for, but still it can be alternative solution. Have a look at [ShareAsImage](http://shareasimage.com/) plugin. It enables you to select a text and share it on pinterest.

Comment: This can be an options, but it allows to share the text with "flat/solid" background.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps you wanna create an image of contents inside   tag and pin it. Use [html2canvas library](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to generate it for you and them you pin it, like:

```
html2canvas($('div section'), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        // pinIt(canvas);
    }
})
```

you may want to look at the examples here at their website:
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you mean, expand on your question so it would be easier to understand what you are having difficulty with.

Maybe use knockout.js to bind the background image, text and pin to an object you can keep recreating on the page. You could use an ajax call to fill in the information during runtime on an event.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I don't understand what you want to accomplish. My understanding is that you want the Text and Image to be togther and put value in runtime?

- Below is done using Jquery.
- For Server side just keep asp:textbox inside h2 tag and then set it
  from server side.
- If you want to add the backround too in run time
  then just remove section's `CSS class` from HTML add `CSS class .section-background` from serverside to Section tag

---

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .section-background {
            background: url('Background.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("h2").text('abc');
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <section class="section-background" >
      <h2></h2>
   </section>

</body>
```

Comment: And how I can pin it to pinterest ?